# get attribute values from returned XML

Tags: iphone

This is the xml I am getting from web:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc>87C4A556-B7E5-5AE4-81FE-86BE0C6306E1</abc>
<abc2>P29077758</abc2>
<abc3>55AGD99D</abc3>
<abc4>147</abc4>
<abc5>1286259226</abc5>
<abc6>USA</abc6>
<abc7>US</abc7>
```

and using this to get attribute:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        recordResults = FALSE;
    //  greeting.text = soapResults;
        [soapResults release];
        soapResults = nil;
    }
}
```

Something like that, but I don't have any idea how can I get attribute from returned xml and assign those returned variables into my created variable. How can I do this?

Comment: If you *really* get this "XML", you're quite screwed. It's not well-formed and no true XML parser will consume it.

Comment: @Boldewyn.... actually i removed real attributes with these example strings...this is not the actual xml my friend.

Answer (score 1):

http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/76999/parsing-xml-files/ hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [TouchXML](http://github.com/schwa/touchcode) to do your XML parsing.

I personally had all kinds of issues with NSXMLParser and ended up using TouchXML. Works a treat!

Comment: will try TouchXML Alastair Pitts.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the following methods:-
One way you can use is :-

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
  {
  //check that the element is the one you want. If it is then initialize the string in which you want to store the value.
  if(elementName isEqualToString:@"abc")
  {
     tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  }
  }
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {

  ```
  [tempString appendString:string];
  ```

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        if(elementName isEqualToString:@"abc")
    {
       self.StringToStore = tempString;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks Javal, but i need to knw, StringToStore this var will store the value of abc right? if i want to assign each values of attribute, i mean,abc1, abc 2 abc3, than wat i hv to do? thanks for reply BTW

Comment: this will store the value between the tags . the code i have written will store value of <abc> tag i.e.(87C4A556-B7E5-5AE4-81FE-86BE0C6306E1). the xml u r having has a tag element and they are not called attributes. Attributes are for e.g <tag1 value="1" name="test"> . here value and name are attributes.

Comment: so for each tag you just need to add if condition checking the element name.

Comment: thats  realy a nice explanation javal, i'll work on that part today....thanks mate

Comment: will this work??   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
 //check that the element is the one you want. If it is then initialize the string in which you want to store the value.
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"abc"])
 {
  tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }
 
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"abc2"]) {
  usernameString = [[NSString alloc] init];
 }
}

Comment: i just put if condition in didstart method.Am i going in a right way.?